# JasperReports very slow when loading JasperPrint file

Tags: java, performance, jasper-reports

I'm loading JasperPrint file and it's taking about 2 seconds to load a 60KB file.

```
String jpXML = .....;
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(jpXML.getBytes("UTF-8"));
JasperPrint jp2 = JRPrintXmlLoader.load(is); //This is taking 2 seconds
```

Does anybody know how to speedup this? The problem seems to be in the XML Digester...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED!!

The JasperPrint load felt from 2000 miliseconds to 10 miliseconds.

I've just updated this dependency from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

To

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So there might be some performance issue with the version 2.10.0 of this lib.